# How can I export the email addresses from a specific gmail folder?

Tags: gmail, google-apps

I am filing (using tags) email set to certain people in a specific folder in a Google Apps gmail account.  Is there a way to export the email addresses of all the people I've emailed for messages in this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late reply but might help someone.

We have looked all over for something to do this at **folder** level, the one we found and use to backup our email addresses was Gmail Email Exporter at [www.starbanana.com](http://starbanana.com)

It exports email addresses that are contained in the email envelope ie To From etc.. so it **doesn't** work directly on the your contacts list only the email addresses found in actual email messages.

Its pretty quick but if you have large amounts of emails you may have to export in chunks as Gmail have some hourly/daily?? limits imposed, this caught us out and took a while to discover what was happening.

I am not connected to this company, I Google'd for ages trying to find a program that works with Folders and was shocked that this was the only one at the time. Come on Google this is basic stuff!!!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built-in to Google Apps does this, but here's what I'd recommend:

1. Export your mail with something like Thunderbird connected to your account over IMAP (POP works too).  Gmail labels will map to folders.
2. Export your mail for that specific label (now a folder in Thunderbird) to a folder on your hard drive.  They'll probably be in a mbox or eml format, both very parseable.
3. Write a script to look at all the email in that folder, extract the email addresses, and then write them to a new csv file.  If you don't know how to get started writing this script, just pay someone to do it - not worth your time, and it's an easy task for someone who knows what they are doing.  I can do it for you if you are interested.

Then you'll have the csv file with all these specific email addresses!

Bonus:

This answer applies more generally, to questions of the form:

"I want to perform some sort of analysis on emails I have in Gmail, but there's no way to do it natively in Gmail."

Comment: I ended up writing scripts that connect over IMAP.